# What is YIQ color model?

Tags: optics, visible-light, vision

As we know that RGB monitors requires separates signals for red, green, and blue components of the image but television monitors uses single composite signals. For this composite signal use YIQ color model.

But don't understand what's the significance of Y, I, Q components? Can anybody explain just the intuition rather than details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Back in the day, when $1$'s and $0$'s were carved out of stone by hand, television was black and white. The TV received a relatively simple signal that just said how intense an electron beam had to be as it scanned back and forth over the phosphor coating the inside surface of a cathode ray tube.

Eventually color TV was invented. The signal now had to be more complex. There were now three types of phosphor, for read, green, and blue colors. There were three beams scanning them. Each beam needed intensity information. But there was a problem.

The straight forward signal for color TV would have been how much red, green, and blue was needed. You can represent all the colors a TV can display with these three numbers. These numbers represent a point in a $3$-D color space. Color space is a lot like a vector space. You can represent a color with an arrow.

But black and white TV did not disappear when relatively few color TVs made their appearance. The same signal had to be used for both types of TV.

The solution was to broadcast the same black and white signal as before. And also to broadcast two new signals for Red and Blue. Black and white TVs would ignore the new signals. It is possible for the TV to figure out how much Green was needed from the total intensity, plus how much intensity was needed for the other two colors. Keep in mind that this was not done with computers. TVs had analog circuits containing vacuum tubes.

This is a new way to represent a color with three numbers. This meant colors were represented as points in a different color space.

There were a variety of standards for exactly which color of red and blue. There were a variety of color spaces as a result. These were collectively called YUV. Y was the black and white intensity signal. U was blue, and V was red. There are other names, such as YCbCr for various standards.

YIQ is similar. Y is intensity. I and Q are color information. But instead of red and blue, I is the color to which the eye is most sensitive. And Q is the color $90^o$ from that. It turns out that I represents colors along the purple-green  axis. And Q is along the orange-blue axis.

The advantage of this is you can get away with not broadcasting as much information in the Q signal. This saves bandwidth. It makes it possible to cram more TV signals in a given range of frequencies. Also it simplified processing. TVs had digital logic by the time YIQ was developed, but it was not as powerful as today's chips.

For more, see the Wikipedia article [YIQ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YIQ).

Comment: Excellent exposition. BTW when I was young we couldn't afford to carve zeroes into stone; management forced us to carve the letter "O" instead and thereby saved Corporate three tenths of a cent per bit in the current FY timeframe.